# fatal error could not load library Counter Strike 1.6

Tags: linux, counter-strike, ubuntu

This is crazy, I don't know how but today I am getting this error alert message `fatal error could not load library++` Counter Strike 1.6 steam in Ubuntu 13.10 its like after some update I guess.

Anyone facing the same?  Any solution?

Thanks
Update: It seems instead of counterstrike steam is loading half life
[image]

Comment: Facing the same problem, this started after a small update today.

Comment: mayb problem injected to promote cs-go

Comment: Half-life 3 confirmed? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the same problem in ubuntu 14.04

problem solved win7

download:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/2mqdj6bcpjaez01/fix+cs+1.6.rar

and put file into the folder:
C:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps\common\Half-Life

Comment: this seems to work check this link http://steamcommunity.com/app/10/discussions/0/558753718112399196/. I have not cross checked yet.